# To prove that $a \in S$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given $f: J \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Let $\alpha \in Image(f)$. Let $S= f^{-1}(\alpha)$. Show that if $(x_n)$
be sequence in S converging to an element in $a \in J$, then $a \in S$

Now $f(x_n) \to f(a)$.

Since $f(x_n)$ $\in$ $Image(f)$. So its limit will also lie in the image of $f$. So $f(a) \in Image(f)$.

How to proceed ? Thanks

Comment: "Since $f(x_n)\in Image(f)$. So its limit will also lie in the image of $f$" is wrong (I mean: there may be sequences in ${\rm im}(f)$ converging to a limit $\notin{\rm im}(f).$ I.e. ${\rm im}(f)$ is not necessarily closed. Example: ${\rm im}(\exp)=(0,+\infty).$ What you must say instead, after your "$f(x_n)\to f(a)$" (due to continuity) is simply $f(x_n)=\alpha,$ hence $f(a)$ (the limit of this constant sequence) is equal to $\alpha,$ i.e. $a\in S.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Assume $f(a) \notin Image(f)$.$ \implies a \notin S $ . $\forall g \in S (f(g) \neq f(a)) $..i am trying to find contradiction here

Comment: Reasoning by contradiction is overcomplicated. The direct proof was in the second part of my prior comment (and again in Danny's answer).

Comment: @AnneBauval oh i was thinking $\alpha$ is any general element in Range of f. But it is one specific element..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $S=\{x\in J\mid f(x)=\alpha\}$ (which is non-empty because
$\alpha\in f(J)$). Suppose that $(x_{n})$ is a sequence in $S$
and $x_{n}\rightarrow a$ for some $a\in J$. Since $f$ is continuous,
we have that $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(a)$. On the other hand, for each
$n$, $x_{n}\in S\Rightarrow f(x_{n})=\alpha$. Hence, the constant
sequence $(\alpha,\alpha,\ldots)$ converges to $f(a)$. It follows
that $f(a)=\alpha\Rightarrow a\in S$.

Remark: If $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by a general topological space
$X$, we need to impose a condition that $X$ is Hausdorff. Otherwise,
we cannot conclude that $\alpha=f(a)$. (For a non-Hausdorff topological
space, a constant sequence $(\alpha,\alpha,\ldots)$ may converge
to a point $b$ with $b\neq\alpha$).

Comment: Sorry I have a question to your remark, could you explain why a constant sequence in a non Hausdorff space may converge to $b$?

Comment: Consider the extreme case that the topology is the trivial topology $\tau=\{\emptyset, X\}$... In this case, every sequence in $X$ is convergent (to an arbitrary point in $X$).

Comment: Ah I see thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $a\notin S=f^{-1}(\alpha)$. Then $f(a)\ne\alpha$. Let $\varepsilon=\bigl|f(a)-\alpha\bigr|$ and consider the interval $\bigl(f(a)-\varepsilon,f(a)+\varepsilon\bigr)$. Since $f$ is continuous, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-a|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-a\bigr|<\varepsilon\iff f(x)\in\bigl(f(a)-\varepsilon,f(a)+\varepsilon\bigr).$$So, if $n\in\Bbb N$, $|x_n-a|\geqslant\delta$, because otherwise $\alpha=f(x_n)\in\bigl(f(a)-\varepsilon,f(a)+\varepsilon\bigr)$, which is impossibel, since $\bigl|f(a)-\alpha\bigr|=\varepsilon$. But then it would not be true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=a$.

---

Or you can just say that $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ is a closed set, since $f$ is continuous and $\{\alpha\}$ is a closed set. So, the limit of any convergent sequence of elements of $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ belongs to $f^{-1}(\alpha)$.

Comment: is my proof wrong ? can it be done furthure ?

Comment: This question is supposed to be done using sequential definition

Comment: Which proof? You simply claim that “So its limit will also lie in the image of $f$”. Where's the proof? That's what you are supposed to prove. Where did you use the fact that $f$ is continuous?